# How to automatically Proxy a DLL(managed) through another DLL(managed)?

Tags: c#, dll, system.reflection

I have a strange request,

Actually our solution is this:

- APP.EXE -> MYDLL.DLL

`APP.EXE` consumes `MYDLL` assembly methods.

Now the client request to implement this variations:

- APP.EXE -> **MYDLL_PROXY.DLL** ->  MYDLL.DLL (load dynamically)

MYDLL_PROXY.DLL must act like a proxy so, calling "MYDLL_PROXY.Method1" would load external MYDLL.DLL and invoke Method1 on it and return the result.

Something like this with reflection:

```
    //MYDLL_PROXY.dll
        ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\mydll.dll");       
        String MyGenericMethod ="Something"
        Type MyType = ass.GetTypes()[0];
        Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(MyType);
        MethodInfo Method = ass.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod(MyGenericMethod);
        return Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { /* parameters go here */ });
```

So, before get mad, there is a quick'n'dirty way to create a fake dll that act like a proxy to another ?

**I need to proxy all : Method, properties, events .**

Thanks for any help.

**NB**: is an old project and must stay with Framework 2.0

---

**Update**

If reflections is not the correct way something like this incapsulate can be possible ? And what about the events ?

ExternalDLL:

```
public class NastyExternalClassInExternalDll
{
    public void Foo() { ... }
}
```

MainDLL:

```
public interface IFooable
{
    void Foo();
}

public sealed class NastyExternalClassWrapper : IFooable
{
    private readonly NastyExternalClassInExternalDll original;

    public NastyExternalClassWrapper(NastyExternalClass original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        original.Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod), [How to: Define and Execute Dynamic Methods - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods) -- [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject)

Comment: is an old project and must stay with Framework 2.0

Comment: so i don't have acces to Dynamic library :/

Comment: Why even use reflection?

Comment: what you suggest @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ? I've already developed a common interface so, the "main-fake-proxy-dll" and the "real-external-dll" implements, 
so now i'm stuck ! I need to "extend" it but i don't know how with a DLL dinamically loaded :/

Comment: i try to better explain this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185848/c-sharp-proxy-different-class-conditionally-at-run-time

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use interfaces like you wrote in your question and wrap all methods\properties. For events, you need to register to them in the proxy also and act.

Other way is to do it with rewriting concept. 
This can be made in two methods.

Statically: read the original dll (with cecil, dnlib etc) and for each method or property you encouraged, call your proxy code, then continue with the actual code. After all, that weaving, save the dll and you have done.
The disadvantage of the static method is that for each change in the original dll, you need to run the wrapper again.

Dynamically: Attach a CLR Profiler to the original dll, and intercept all calls to your code before any method or property call.

I can't go further deeply here for each of these methods, because it will be long, but you can read on them and if you have a specific question, let me know.

Comment: for the rewriting solution what about the events ? 

let say, app call mydll_proxy.dll method "START" , rewrite to "mydll.dll" : start 

after that mydll throw a "started" events but now how i can pass back the events to mydll_proxy.dll ? 

Maybe with the interface is more simple listen the events ? i try to focus on this task in the next days. Thanks for all

Comment: Few options. 1 - Handle it on the subscriber side. If no one subscribes to it, pass it. Otherwise, handle it as you handle other methods with the rewrite techniques. 2 - Subscribe yourself to the event. For example, search for Delegate.Combine call instruction and subscribe yourself. 3 - Call your code for each invocation, search for callvirt instruction to Invoke or DynamicInvoke and call to your code.

Comment: It's really in a nutshell. Each of the methods has its advantages and disadvantages and each has end-cases to consider. If you have access to the original dll and you can change it ie make it implement an interface and the original code is not going to change then maybe your method is the most suitable really. It will be easiest for programmers to come after you because the solution's learning curve is simple. If there are restrictions and other requirements sometimes there is no escape from another, more dynamic method with the most flexibility.

Comment: Anyway, what is stopping you right now in the solution you started with the interface?

Comment: aside from having time to spend on this task, yes, i stop myself on events from interface, but i think the subscriptions way + interface is the best and "clean" way i can choose from. Thanks.